# How to dispaly a map and get the centre coordinates - latitude and longitude?

Tags: iphone, mapkit

Hi i wanted to know how to display a map on my view and then retrieve the centre coordinates (latitude and longitude).

I have been able to do the reverse of getting the coordinates of my current location and displaying on my map.Please help.

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a MKMapView:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapView_Class/MKMapView/MKMapView.html

To get the center coordinate:

`myMapView.centerCoordinate`